# Can't create and select valid iOS In-App-Purchase

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

First off, I've found tons of help regarding this topic but none seem to fit my specific situation.

So on iTunes connect I'm trying to add an IAP to my app. All the steps to do so are done (say I signed the paid application contract and I'm admin)

[image]
I have an "approved" in app purchase and one "ready to submit".

Next up when I try to add it to my app, only the ready one is shown. In fact if I don't have an IAP with "ready to submit" status, the whole section is not visible.

[image]

And when I try to fetch either of these product Id's they both seem to be invalid...

```
  public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("Loaded list of products...")
    let products = response.products

    for invalidId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers {
      print("invalid: \(invalidId)")
    }

    for p in products {
      print("Found product: \(p.productIdentifier) \(p.localizedTitle) \(p.price.floatValue)")
    }
  }
```

[image]

Is there something I'm missing? Do I have to submit a working version first? I'd like to have more interactive debugging considering the ~2 day review time.

I thought I would just be able to use an approved IAP, and the Apple documentation doesn't show any more steps than I have already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the one shown in the second screenshot (when you add them to your app) is the "Ready to Submit" one, check the Product ID, it says: `ads`

So everything is good, when you send your app for review it will be reviewed too.

As for them being invalid I think you might be using wrong identifiers when requesting them, as far as I can see on the console screenshot you are requesting them as: `shomething.remove_ads` and apparently the product id is only: `remove_ads`

Comment: I'm so mad hahahaha, from what I found the string you send has to be `bundleIdentifier` + `productId`, I never thought about only using the `productId`.

Comment: You are right, the documentation on how to use `productId` for purchases is quite incomplete and confusing. I recommend you to use `bundleIdentifier.productId` on any future IAP you create, it will help you organise them better.

Comment: Oh I get it now, that makes perfect sense actually.